# How to differentiate the screen on which users interact with push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I am curious to know the screen on which a user interacts with a push notification. Currently this can be the lock screen, the notification tray, or the app badge. Is there a way that can help me tell what screen the user interacted with a notification?

Comment: Not sure if the functionality exists or not, but if it exists, it should be in the intent you receive that is triggered by the notification. This is my best guess

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to tell which screen a user interacted with when they received a push notification. The notification handling logic in your app is triggered the same way whether a user interacts with a push notification on the lock screen, the notification tray, or the app badge.